# Laravel Socialite using Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working on a project which uses:

```
* Laravel 5.1
* hipsterjazzbo/LaraParse version 0.1.6 (https://github.com/hipsterjazzbo/LaraParse)
```

The problem is I want to use Socialite (https://github.com/laravel/socialite) to add google authentication. But when I run

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

It says that I need at least Laravel 5.6 to use it. But I cannot update laravel because laraparse requires laravel 5.1.

What is my best option here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though from the [doc](https://github.com/hipsterjazzbo/LaraParse)

> LaraParse provides a nice integration for using Parse (parse.com) with Laravel 5+.

This means it's ok to use LaraParse with 5.6. So you can update your laravel project.

**However, according to this [issue](https://github.com/hipsterjazzbo/LaraParse/issues/52), it does not support 5.3 and above.**

So if you have to use `Socialite`. You need to use a different library for `Parse`

You can try this: [Laravel-Parse](https://github.com/LaravelParse/Laravel-Parse)

Or try to use a lower version of socialite

```sh
composer require laravel/socialite ^2.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm getting this error whenever I update Laravel version to 5.6 in composer.json and running composer update:                                                           
 Problem 1
    - hipsterjazzbo/laraparse v0.1.6 requires laravel/framework 5.0.*|5.1.*|5.2.* -> satisfiable by lara...